How to extract Physical table from hyper file column definition
If you open a hyper file saved from extract in Tableau and inspect the data source ( Which usually is Extract.Extract) you will see the Field Name, Physical Column and Remote Field name. However this is not available in Hyper API (see the code below) I can only get the field name and the field type but not Physical Columns and Remote field. Is there other way to query it ?
    def GetHyperStructure(self, hyperfile):
    with HyperProcess(Telemetry.DO_NOT_SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU) as hyper:
        with Connection(endpoint=hyper.endpoint, database=hyperfile) as connection:

            table_names = connection.catalog.get_table_names(schema="Extract")

            for table in table_names:
                table_definition = connection.catalog.get_table_definition(name=table)
                print(f"Table {table.name} has qualified name: {table}")
                for column in table_definition.columns:
                    print(f"Column {column.name} has type={column.type} and nullability={column.nullability}")
                


Ended up parsing the xml data and fishing out table names. It is not documented so it is sill better to use official API if it exists
def Get_TdsTables(self, tdsx_file, tmp_dir):

    local_tds = TableauFileManager.open(filename=tdsx_file)
    tdsfile = local_tds.packaged_filename
    Path(tmp_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    tmp_file = os.path.join(tmp_dir, os.path.basename(tdsfile))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tdsx_file) as z:
        with z.open(tdsfile) as zf, open(
            tmp_file, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f)

    tree = ET.parse(tmp_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    parents = root.findall('.//parent-name')
    tables = []
    for parent in parents:
        table = str(parent.text).replace('[','').replace(']', '')
        if not table in tables:
            tables.append(table)

    return tables

